# Diffrent column names

Tags: csv, ssis

I have 74 `csv` files.

I am merging in **SSIS**. The data in all are the same, but the column names are different in half.

How can I do mapping?

The column name is [Latitude] in one sample file and [Lat] in the other.

Comment: uncheck 1st row contains headers and start on row 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column ordinal position for Latitude/Lat is always the same i.e. third column in the file, then you can modify your flat file connection manager to skip the first row and that your file does not have header rows. This will result in you having to manually define your file layout but it's entirely workable.

If lat is column 4 in one file and Latitude is always column 1, the best solution is to have two connection managers - one for each file type and segment your data files by folder and route them into different foreach file enumerators and dataflows for consumption by the target tables.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I did it as you say and I fixed it. Thanks